# ¿Porque me sale " array required, but int found "?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa para la escuela y no entiendo porque me sale este error me pueden ayudar por favor.
Alguien sabe que esta mal?, es un proyecto por lo tanto tengo una clase con un arreglo bidimensional y me pide hacer esto:

> Permite mostrar todas las publicaciones realizadas en el sistema, se debe leer el arreglo e imprimir las filas en un formato entendible y adecuado para que el usuario pueda observarlas. En la impresión de las publicaciones se debe agregar una línea entre cada una de ellas de la siguiente forma:
>
> JoseSanchez- FlorGarcia > El reporte de fin de mes se presentó el 10 de noviembre de 2020.
>
> FlorGarcia - JoseSanchez > De acuerdo, ya se ha hecho la revisión pertinente.
>
> MariaLopez - Todos > Es muy importante cumplir los objetivos de la organización."

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    boolean salir = false;
    String usuarioA = "", usuarioB = "", mensaje = "", saltoDeLinea = "";
    int publicaciones = 0;
    int opcion = 0;
    int arreglo = 0;
    int repetirR = 0;
    int repetirD = 0;
    int repetirM = 0;
    int contAr = 0;
    int contTotal = 0;
    SocialBD socialBD = new SocialBD();
    //SocialBD.insertaDatosIniciales(); //Permite inicializar el arreglo con 2 libros 
    
    System.out.println("\t\tHola! Sea bienvenido a social Text");
     while(!salir) {
      System.out.println("Por favor, eleiga una opccion");
      System.out.println("\n1-Ver todas las publicaciones,\n2- Ver publicaciones por conversación,\n3-Agregar publicacion,\n4-Salir ");
      opcion = scanner.nextInt(); ;

      switch(opcion){
        case 1:
          System.out.println("\t\tVer todas las publicaciones");

          do {
        System.out.print(publicaciones [repetirR][0]);
        System.out.print(" - ");
        System.out.print(publicaciones [repetirD][1]);
        System.out.print(" > ");
        System.out.println(publicaciones [repetirM][2]);
        System.out.println(" ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ");
   
        repetirR++;
       repetirD++;
        repetirM++;
        arreglo++;

      } while(contAr <= contTotal); //Este ciclo do while imprime todas las publicaciones que se han hecho/
      
  repetirR = 0;
      repetirD = 0;
      repetirM = 0;    //Aquí reinician sus valores para que la proxima vez que se abra la publicación se muestren de nuevo/
      arreglo = 1;
          break;
```

El error me sale aquí

```
  System.out.print(publicaciones [repetirR][0]);
        System.out.print(" - ");
        System.out.print(publicaciones [repetirD][1]);
        System.out.print(" > ");
        System.out.println(publicaciones [repetirM][2]);
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Por favor, añade más código, si es posible el código completo, ya que no se puede saber con lo que has puesto el tipo de las variables.

Comment: Me sumo a lo del colega @ordago, mas esas sumas que estas realizando al final me causan curiosidad. Estas tratando de sumar 1 a una variable de tipo arreglo, por ahí debería estar el problema

Comment: Has declarado publicaciones como entero pero lo tratas de usar como array.

Comment: No solo eso, los `repetir`los está agregando dentro del mismo modo. Si declaras como int (numerico) la variable, debes trabajarla como int, pero estás cargandola como si se tratara de un array

Comment: es que la variable `publicaciones` es un entero, no un array, así que no puedes hacer cosas como `publicaciones[i][j]`. El mensaje es muy claro.

Comment: @SuperG280 podrías ponerlo como respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Por que no es una respuesta el explicar el error que claramente se menciona. Una respuesta sería corregir dicho error, pero el OP no se ha presentado frente a lo ya mencionado, y creo que eso esperamos todos.

Answer (score 1):

Si revisas la definición de la variable `repetirR`, es un entero:

```
 int repetirR = 0;
```

Por lo tanto donde se muestra el error,

> "Matriz requerida, pero int encontrado"

estas indicando que se obtenga un valor de un array¿?, lo cual es incorrecto ya que  `repetirR` es solo un entero:

```
    System.out.print(publicaciones [repetirR][0]);
    System.out.print(" - ");
    System.out.print(publicaciones [repetirD][1]);
    System.out.print(" > ");
    System.out.println(publicaciones [repetirM][2]);
```

Comment: Es lo que le hemos dicho desde hace horas !!